# Why training loss is increased at the beginning of each epoch?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm training a linear regression model. I use tf.contrib.data to prepare the dataset, shuffle it and serve it in batches:

```
  dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
  dataset = dataset.map(
      _parse_function, num_threads=16, output_buffer_size=100 * batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(5)
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
  dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=([None], [None]))
  iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
  x_inputs, y_ = iterator.get_next()
```

The following is our training loss:
[image: training loss]

It is very strange that at the beginning of each epoch (iteration=100k) we have a pulse in the training loss. If the training process continues, we see the same pattern at the beginning of the following epochs.

Comment: If you provide the minimal code to reproduce your problem, it will be much easier to answer. But probably the problem is in the order of your data.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your dataset has fewer than 100000 records, the problem could be insufficient randomness in the input shuffle. Intuitively, if the existing data are not shuffled and have some structure in their order, the training process could overfit to the records towards the end of the file, and when you restart at the beginning, the model will not perform as well on the records near the beginning of the file, and the loss will increase.

The proper solution will depend on the precise details of your dataset, but some of the following approaches might be useful:

1. If possible, increase the `buffer_size` you pass to `Dataset.shuffle()` to be as large as the dataset. (This might not be possible if your entire dataset doesn't fit in memory.)
2. Ensure that the data does not have any structure in the ordering of records by randomizing the order of the input file before training.
3. In addition to randomizing the order within the file, you could partition the data into several different files, and randomize the order in which you visit those files using the following:

   ```
   dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(shard_filenames)
   dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(shard_filenames))
   dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename))
   # ...
   ```
4. As an extension of (3), you could use `Dataset.interleave()` in place of `Dataset.flat_map()` to read multiple shards at once .

Comment: I have a million training set and tried to increase buffer_size to million but the problem does not solve.
I found that this may be an issue from 'sampled_softmax'. when I change it to other (for ex. 'rank_sampled_softmax'), I dont see this pattern in the training loss. Any ideas?

Comment: As David suggested in his comment, we'd need to see more of the code and have some way to reproduce the problem to come up with more ideas. If indeed the sampled softmax is the problem, we'd have no way to guess that from the question :).

Comment: @mrry I'm having the same problem. Could the ordering of the data really be the reason? The argument that the training process might overfit towards the end of the epoch does not seem plausible to me. The model can only overfit if it sees the same data over and over again, which is not the case over the course of one epoch over the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

The same sawtooth pattern is seen here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/strange-behavior-with-sgd-momentum-training/7442

The suggested solution there is to insure your data loader loads the data WITH replacement.

Comment: This linked question is not exactly the same sawtooth pattern, and has a different cause. In the case of the link, there was a drop in the loss at the beginning of each epoch, followed by an increase during the epoch. In the case of the OP, there was a jump in the loss at the beginning of the epoch, followed by a decline during the epoch.